# Entity Framework : ObjectContext safety

Tags: sql, entity-framework, objectcontext

I'm developing n-tier application that consists of 4 web applications 
and one windows service and I would like to have one instance of ObjectContext per http request or one per thread.

The question is should I handle situations where I would have instances of ObjectContext in both webapp and winservice and for example in webapp I'm editing record, in winservice I'm deleting the same record. Is there any possibility both processes will hit Context.SaveChanges() at the same time and what will happen if it's possible?

Answer (score 0):

The update will throw an exception if the delete happens to occur first.  Otherwise the update will succeed and then the delete will succeed.

If you had a case where you were both did a select then update, then

Thread A select

Thread B select

Thread A update

Thread B update, but through exception because it detects that record has changed.

It does this using what is known as optimistic concurrency.  When thread b does the update, it includes in the where criteria all of the values it selected.  If any do not match then the update will not modify any records, and EF will throw an exception.